# Watch for change in ip address status

Tags: .net, windows

Is there a way to watch for changes in the ip-address much the same as it is possible to watch for changes to files using the FileSystemWatcher? I'm connecting to a machine via tcp/ip but it takes a while until it gives me an ip-address. I would like to dim out the connect button until I have a valid ip-address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [NetworkChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) class. It raises an event when a network address changes.